# Is there a java.util.concurrent class that will allow periodic starting of threads without blocking for completion?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have the following requirement.

I am trying to build a simulator that will generate load on a system for the purpose of load testing.  I want threads to start every X milliseconds, each of which will kick off a task that takes Y milliseconds, with Y being maybe 2 or 3 orders of magnitude > X.

I had thought I could use ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate().  It hasn't worked.  I see the following javadoc comment which explains why:

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
>   subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently
>   execute.

Concurrent execution is precisely what I want.  I want to start a lot of tasks in separate threads, let them do whatever they do, with a big thread pool, and finish when they finish.  The point is to generate load for testing load.

Is there anything available in java.util.concurrent that would let me do so?  I am reading these javadocs but they are making my head spin now.

Comment: Have you considered [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Do you want to do something like start a new thread every 10 milliseconds, have each thread run 1000 milliseconds and then die? Over time the load will increase. Why not just start a new thread every 10 millis? Why use a thread pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `scheduleAtFixedRate(control, 10l, 1l, TimeUnit.SEDONDS)` scheduler to create and execute new tasks (in other threads), similar to:

```
    final ScheduledExecutorService pool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(100);
    Runnable control = new Runnable()
    {
      public void run() {
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             // do work here
          }
        };
        pool.execute(task);
      };
    };
    pool.scheduleAtFixedRate(control, 5l, 1l, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: And as an addition be sure to calculate the pool size correctly. If your task runs max 100ms and you want to start one every 10ms you need at least 100ms/10ms + 1 = 11 Threads for this to work.

Comment: @eckes - How does this get around the limitation I posted in the original post?  "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute."

Comment: @SteveCohen The actual work is submitted as a different task to the Executor using `Executor.execute(...)`. So your fixed rate task now does no longer exceed its period time.

Comment: @Gandalf - so what you're saying is that pool.execute(task) returns immediately, regardless of the time it takes for task to run()?  That would solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, instead of the scheduled taqsk you could also have a control thread which loops/sleeps. Or you start all tasks at the beginning (with increasing initial delays). But in all cases it gets submitted to the pool and that one execute with the maximum parallelity configured.

Comment: @SteveCohen According to the JavaDoc this depends on the Executor you use. If you use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` without a `CallerRunsPolicy` this should work. But at the end the policy only kicks in if you have to few threads.

Comment: @Gandalf  (and Eckes too) - thanks very much.  This simple solution is how I originally thought this should work, but I was misled by the notion that scheduling or executing a task was not the same as waiting for it to complete.  My confusion as to my results was due to a logging failure.